# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SHG_LOAN_QRY'

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am getting an error "PLS 00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to...." while calling a Oracle stored procedure from java

following is my java code :

```
public ResultSet callShgLoansQry(String comCode,String mainCode,String unitCode,String shgno,String lsrid)
throws SQLException{
Array arr = null;
String query = "{call shg_loans_qry(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
cstmt = con.prepareCall(query);
cstmt.setString(1, comCode );
cstmt.setString(2, mainCode );
cstmt.setString(3, unitCode);
cstmt.setString(4, shgno);
cstmt.setString(5, lsrid);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(6, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"LOAN_DTS_TAB");
cstmt.execute();
arr = cstmt.getArray(6);
return arr.getResultSet();
}
```

following is my stored procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE shg_loans_qry(V_COMP IN VARCHAR2,V_MAIN IN VARCHAR2,V_UNIT IN VARCHAR2,V_SHG IN VARCHAR2,V_EMP_ID IN VARCHAR2,loan_rec_Tab out shg_qry.loan_dts_tab) AS
cursor c1 is select  A.COMP_CODE,A.MAIN_CODE,a.unit_code,a.loan_no,a.csa_code,b.client_name ,c.emp_id,b.regis_group,D.int_rate,D.INT_TYPE,
D.last_disbdate disbdt,D.total_disbamt disbamt,a.client_code,b.phone_nos
from bo119_prodsanction_mst a
,bo501_regis_hdr b
,cm010_emp_mst c
,BO301_LOAN_SUMM D where ..........
```

and this is my shg_qry.loan_dts_tab :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE shg_qry is
type loan_rec is Record (
comp_code varchar2(3),
main_code varchar2(3),
unit_code varchar2(3),
loan_no varchar2(10),
CLIENT_NAME Varchar2(100),
client_code varchar2(100),
shg_group_name varchar2(100),
mobile_no varchar2(20),
os_amt number,
TOBE_COLL number,
os_Prin number,
Od_Prin number,
Os_Int number,
Od_Int number,
od_icr number,
os_icr number,
inst_int number,
inst_prn number,
inst_icr number);
loan_dtls loan_rec;
type loan_dts_tab is table of loan_dtls%type index by binary_integer;
end shg_qry;
```

Comment: How/why do you have a package with the same name as your procedure? You can't get a `TABLE` type back with `OracleTypes.CURSOR`. Look into `OracleTypes.ARRAY`...

Comment: Thanks Alex Poole for your reply, while using OracleTypes.ARRAY I am getting : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation